# Printing out values of rows using itertuples() that differ in columns (to not print out empty cells)

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel sheet containing the following:

```
key     topic   a      b      c      d     e
plants  flower  red    blue   green  pink  purple
space   moon    grey   blue   white
bugs    ants    red    black
```

Simplified, what I want is to 'print' out each row to separate files, like so:

```
file1.txt:
a) It is red.
b) It is blue.
c) It is green.
d) It is pink.
e) It is purple.

file2.txt:
a) It is grey.
b) It is blue.
c) It is white.

file3.txt:
a) It is red.
b) It is black.
```

But as you can see, each row contains a differing amount of columns. I.e., there are empty cells that I do not want to have printed out.

I don't want a file like so:

```
a) It is red.
b) It is black.
c) 
d) 
e)
```

This is my code so far:

```py
for row in df.itertuples():
    ques = open("file1.txt","w+")
    ques.write('It is '+row.a+'.')
    ques.write('It is '+row.b+'.')
    ques.write('It is '+row.c+'.')
    ques.write('It is '+row.d+'.')
    ques.write('It is '+row.e+'.')
```

This then throws an error `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str`. I'm almost certain it's because there's nothing in columns d,e and c,d,e for the second and third questions.

(And yes, I know this code will repeatedly print to the same file1.txt but I've simplified the code to focus on my main issue, which is the rows not having the same amount of columns.)

So then I tried:

```
    for index in df.itertuples():
        ques.write(row.index)
```

I get this error: `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "builtin_function_or_method") to str`.

I've also tried:

```
    if row.c is not None:
         ques.write('It is '+row.c+'.')
    if row.d is not 0:
         ques.write('It is '+row.d+'.')
# etc
```

This also throws an error.

I know somehow I must use a loop, but after searching around I'm a bit at a loss. My main issue is that I do not want the empty cells to be printed out.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

I have tried `ques.write(','.join(i for i in row[1:] if i is not np.NaN))` and while that works to not throw an error, it now prints out everything into a line. "plants,flower,red,blue,green,pink,purple".

Comment: Do you want the column header (a, b,c d) in your output file ?

Comment: No, it does not matter.

Comment: Can't you just adjust the row first, i.e. `ques.write([i for i in row if i is not None])`?

Comment: @HenryYik I'm not quite sure what you mean. Wouldn't that print out everything in the row, including the beginning things like "plants, flowers"? I only want to print out the a,b,c,d,e values, IF they are not empty.

Comment: I mean do it during your iterrtuples.

Comment: @HenryYik I tried, it, still getting `TypeError: write() argument must be str, not list`.

Comment: `ques.write(“,”.join(i for i in row if i is not None)).`

Comment: @HenryYik Now I'm getting `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found`

Comment: Hmm it looks like your first item is a integer instead. Try row[1:] instead of row then.

Comment: @HenryYik Now it says `TypeError: sequence item 9: expected str instance, float found`. My excel sheet is a bit different from my example excel sheet. At item 9 there is an empty cell.

Comment: I can’t guess everything error you face. The idea is filter out unwanted data by list comprehension, join the list, and write to your file. If None is not correct, maybe use np.NaN.

Comment: @HenryYik That worked to not throw an error! I will need to do some more testing to have it properly show up the way I want it to though. But thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try type casting it to string.

in

```
df=temp_df.copy() 
df=df.drop(columns=['key','topic'],axis="columns")
for row in df.itertuples(): 
   #print(row) 
   for x in row: 
   if isinstance(x,str): 
       print(x,type(x))
```

Comment: The issue is, I don't want it to print out empty cells. I have edited my question to make this more clear.

Comment: ```df=temp_df.copy()
df=df.drop(columns=['key','topic'],axis="columns")
for row in df.itertuples():
    #print(row)
    for x in row:
        if isinstance(x,str):
            print(x,type(x))
```
see This prints only non empty cells of each row.
temp_df: your initial dataframe loaded from file

Comment: Could you edit this into your answer? It's a bit hard to read in the comments. I will try this though.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the file line by line and just print everything after the second column:

```
with open(filename, "r") as f: 
    headers = next(f).split() 
    count = 1 
    for line in f: 
        line = line.split() 
        with open(f"file{count}.txt", "w") as outf: 
            outf.write("\n".join(line[2:])) 
        count += 1
```

EDIT: If your input file can have empty columns in the middle for instance (last line):

```
key     topic   a      b      c      d     e
plants  flower  red    blue   green  pink  purple
space   moon    grey   blue   white
bugs    ants    red    black
food    pasta   blue   pink         purple green
```

It won't work, so if you have cases like this just let me know and I'll edit

Comment: I can try this, but ideally I would like to use itertuples(), because the rest of my code is relying on that.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by doing this:

```py
if row.c is not np.NaN:
   ques.write('It is '+row.c+'.')
if row.d is not np.NaN:
   ques.write('It is '+row.d+'.')
if row.e is not np.NaN:
   ques.write('It is '+row.e+'.')
```

Not really a loop so it can't be scaled up, but otherwise it works. Thanks to Henry Yik in the comments for the `np.NaN`.